# Name scope issue when running Excel add-in on Office Web

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, add-in

I'm sporadically getting an **ItemAlreadyExists** exception when adding named ranges in my Excel add-in, and that also only when running Excel in a browser (not desktop).

The code is pretty straight-forward. For each worksheet, I add a named range called 'rulescape_ids'. This is expected to be scoped for the worksheet as per the [api docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#names).

```
        private prepareAddNamedIdRange(): void {
            const namedRangeItem = this.sheet.names.getItemOrNullObject(this.idRangeName);
            if (namedRangeItem) {
                namedRangeItem.delete();
            }
            let idRange = this.headerCell.getRowsBelow(this.usedRangeLastCell.rowIndex + 100); // occasionally causing itemAlreadyExists on Office Web!!
            this.sheet.names.add(this.idRangeName, idRange);
        }
```

Exception details:

```
{"code":"ItemAlreadyExists","message":"A resource with the same name or identifier already exists.","errorLocation":"NamedItemCollection.add","statement":"var add=names.add(...);","surroundingStatements":["...","// Instantiate {rowsBelow}","var workbook=context.workbook;","var worksheets=workbook.worksheets;","var worksheet=worksheets.getItem(...) /* originally getItem(...) */;","var names=worksheet.names;","// >>>>>","var add=names.add(...);","// <<<<<","var v1=context.workbook._getObjectByReferenceId(\"R!{210136D6-71B5-4BF2-BEA0-9CBDA9AA57D1}!{C06F41B8-B778-4030-8D38-51BBA2FD9FAF}\") /* originally find(...) */;","var rowsBelow1=v1.getRowsBelow(...);","// Instantiate {rowsBelow1}","var worksheet1=worksheets.getItem(...) /* originally getItem(...) */;","var names1=worksheet1.names;","..."],"fullStatements":["var v=context.workbook._getObjectByReferenceId(\"R!{55F88602-7FD7-4AD4-A8D6-1B8578F08275}!{C06F41B8-B778-4030-8D38-51BBA2FD9FAF}\") /* originally find(\"_header\", {\"completeMatch\":true,\"matchCase\":true,\"searchDirection\":\"Forward\"}) */;","var rowsBelow=v.getRowsBelow(106);","// Instantiate {rowsBelow}","var workbook=context.workbook;","var worksheets=workbook.worksheets;","var worksheet=worksheets.getItem(\"{00000000-0001-0000-1000-000000000000}\") /* originally getItem(\"transaction fee data\") */;","var names=worksheet.names;","var add=names.add(\"rulescape_ids\", rowsBelow, undefined);","var v1=context.workbook._getObjectByReferenceId(\"R!{210136D6-71B5-4BF2-BEA0-9CBDA9AA57D1}!{C06F41B8-B778-4030-8D38-51BBA2FD9FAF}\") /* originally find(\"_header\", {\"completeMatch\":true,\"matchCase\":true,\"searchDirection\":\"Forward\"}) */;","var rowsBelow1=v1.getRowsBelow(112);","// Instantiate {rowsBelow1}","var worksheet1=worksheets.getItem(\"{00000000-0001-0000-0B00-000000000000}\") /* originally getItem(\"loan data\") */;","var names1=worksheet1.names;","var add1=names1.add(\"rulescape_ids\", rowsBelow1, undefined);","var v2=context.workbook._getObjectByReferenceId(\"R!{C1D50634-EBC2-4DDB-9D0F-494CB24980D8}!{C06F41B8-B778-4030-8D38-51BBA2FD9FAF}\") /* originally find(\"_header\", {\"completeMatch\":true,\"matchCase\":true,\"searchDirection\":\"Forward\"}) */;"...
```

After the exception, when I open the workbook in Excel desktop and view the Name Manager, I see that a name has been created with "Workbook" scope as shown in the screenshot below, which explains the ItemAlreadyExists exception when the name is created for the next worksheet. But why is this name being created in "Workbook" scope?

[Name Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL0mM.png)

When I repeat the operation, it behaves correctly with names scoped to the worksheet and no exception is thrown.

What could be the underlying issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see with your code is that it is not using the `getItemOrNullObject` method properly. You have to do a context.sync after call this method before you test for nullity. Also, you don't test for nullity with `if (namedItemRange)`. You test with `if (namedItemRange.isNullObject)`. For details, see [*OrNullObject Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-advanced-concepts#ornullobject-methods). I don't know if this will fix your problem, but its a fix you need to make anyway, and maybe it will stop the error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Rick. I still get the error after implementing your suggestions. Do I also need a sync after the namedRangeItem.delete() and before the sheet.names.add(...)?

Comment: Please provide more of the code. We need to see what your `this` is. Also, we need to see the entire `Excel.run()`.

Comment: Thanks for offering to look at the code. The code spans multiple somewhat large classes. I'll try to whittle it down to its essence and send an extract.